# SSH Config ProxyJump - Port forwarding from proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy, ssh-config

i have a question regarding port forwarding in combination with proxy jump in my ssh config:

Is it possible to make use of `DynamicForward` from the host used as proxy? Here's my config:

```
Host proxy
    HostName proxy.private.com
    User user
    IdentityFile ~/path/to/file
    DynamicForward 3000

Host target
    HostName target.somewhere.com
    User user
    IdentityFile ~/path/to/file
    ProxyJump proxy
```

It does not work with this config, but this would be exactly what i need.
Any tips on how to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing preventing you from using [ProxyCommand](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ProxyCommand) you can most likely use this approach:

In your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host target
        HostName target.somewhere.com
        User target-user
        IdentityFile ~/path/to/target-user-file
        ProxyCommand ssh -A <proxy-user>@<proxy-host> -i <proxy-user-key> -W %h:%p
        DynamicForward 3000
```

You can then run this command on your local machine:

```
ssh target -D 3000
```

I was able to test this by running this command locally and retreiving public IP of the target host:

```
curl -x socks5h://localhost:3000 https://ifconfig.me/
```

Usefull links I read:

- More details on these use cases can be found [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-ssh-proxycommand-passing-through-one-host-gateway-server/)
- Detail on this very approach can be found on [this site](http://www.ixany.org/docs/OpenSSH_tunnels.html#exemple_ssh_config) (sadly not in english nor HTTPS)

You can probably define another Host on top to avoid having to mess with ssh parameter each time. This would be done by using [CanonicalizeHostname](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#CanonicalizeHostname), but I couldn't manage to it. An alias might be more interesting at that point ?